# Is it safe to extract file from potentially infected disk

Tags: malware, disk-image

I have a hard drive used for years, there are windows and many personal files on it. What I called "files" are images, musics, documents (pdf or docx), but not programs. All the "files" were not initially infected. As I said in the title, the hard drive may be infected by malware (I did not safely use it).

My question is : can I extract these personal files on a safe computer without risk of contamination ? In other words, may these files be infected and spread malware ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the malware.

A "classic" malware would be a *single* executable, usually spread by a third party via email attachment and not autonomously spreading itself *by piggy-backing on files* (it might spread itself through disk shares or the filesystem, but making copies of its executable, not altering other files); so, while it might *destroy* (or encrypt, which is often the same thing in this business) your documents, it would not *infect* them.

A *computer virus* or *worm* **could** infect Office documents with macros and PDFs with malicious Javascript as a means of spreading itself. With a very, very low probability it could also conceivably hide malicious code in certain types of images and videos.

In the first case, the disk is safe **as long as you never execute any binary file it contains and limit yourself to copying documents, images, video, music; never programs**.

In the second case (the virus), the disk **is not safe**, any document it contains is potentially suspect, and actually **even plugging it into a clean computer** might compromise the latter; this is because there might be an AutoPlay exploit (you can make it so every time you plug a flash drive or other media into a PC, a specific file on that media is executed; the same can be done, with more difficulty, with a specially crafted icon file usually used to associate the device with a recognizable or branded image).

However, scanning the disk with a reliable antivirus (from a system designed to be safe against AutoPlay and icon exploits) should clear any doubt. Another possibility is to use an antivirus bootable CD-ROM (e.g. ESET or Kaspersky), that will start an antivirus environment designed not to contaminate the primary hard disk.

Comment: I agree with your answer... but for the last line.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I used "malware" because I thought it is the more general term for any malicious program.

Comment: @Ángel yes, I think I understand your meaning. I tried to amend the answer.

Comment: A huge thanks ! That is exactly what I wonder. You help me a lot !

Comment: In that case, be sure to accept the answer (there is a mark to do so under its score)